# Getting position information from JSON token in source

Tags: json, ocaml

I'm using `yojson` to parse a JSON file in OCaml, and while I'm validating the input file, I'd like to emit error messages containing source code information for the user.

For instance, if I found that a given value at line 5492 is not in the allowed range, I'd like to tell the user: "Invalid value in line source.json:5492".

How can I get this information?

(If yojson cannot give this kind of information, another OCaml JSON library that does have this information might be useful.)

Comment: From what I understand it can't, but atdgen can. I've used neither though, just passing on what I've heard.

Comment: @glennsl `atdgen` looks indeed interesting, but from the documentation here: https://mjambon.github.io/atdgen-doc/atdgen#field-validator, it seems to me that you can provide a location information based on the path in the json tree, which means that instead of `source.json:5492`, OP might end up with something like `path = <root>[1472].foo`, which is admittedly better than nothing, but not by much (not that I have a better proposal to make, though).

Comment: To have complete control and context of where you are while parsing, you might be better off creating a json parser from scratch using something like ocamllex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In between efficiency and interactivity, `Yojson` has chosen the first (More accurately, `Yojson` is really designed for data (de)serialisation, so computer generated JSON where error reporting makes no sense).

Its lever file: `yojson/lib/read.mll` starts by the exact comment:

```
(*
  We override Lexing.engine in order to avoid creating a new position
  record each time a rule is matched.
  This reduces total parsing time by about 31%.
*)
```

These positions are exactly what you need to report errors!

`Jsonm` has what you need:

```
val decoded_range : decoder -> (int * int) * (int * int)
decoded_range d is the range of characters spanning the last `Lexeme or `Error (or `White or `Comment for an Jsonm.Uncut.decode) decoded by d. A pair of line and column numbers respectively one and zero based.
```

but `Jsonm` is a library for experts.

Sadly, its wrapper `Ezjsonm` does nearly the good thing but fails at the last second and raise `Ezjsonm.Parse_error` with no range!

You can have a look at the source code as inspiration to do the right thing at https://github.com/mirage/ezjsonm/blob/master/lib/ezjsonm.ml : `json_of_src` does exactly what you need but then ... for unknown reason ... `from_src` defined as

```
let from_src src =
  match json_of_src src with
  | `JSON t      -> t
  | `Error (_,e) -> parse_error `Null "JSON.of_buffer %s" (string_of_error e)

let from_string str = from_src (`String str)
```

drops the range!

Comment: It seems Ezjsonm changed the code since, and skimming it quickly, I do not see the error argument being dropped, but instead, a `loc ()` being added. Maybe it works now?